# How to set default time zone in Nestjs?

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-config

I tried below script but it didn't work.

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "TZ='UTC' nest start"
  }
}
```

[System Information]
OS Version     : Linux 5.4
NodeJS Version : v12.18.3
NPM Version    : 6.14.6

[Nest CLI]
Nest CLI Version : 7.4.1

[Nest Platform Information]
platform-express version : 7.0.0
passport version         : 7.0.0
typeorm version          : 7.1.0
common version           : 7.0.0
config version           : 0.5.0
core version             : 7.0.0
jwt version              : 7.0.0

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In a REPL, this is working as expected.

```sh
TZ=UTC node
> d = new Date()
> d.toLocaleTimeString()
```

I would assume you need to set your start command as

```
  "start": "TZ=UTC nest start"
```